# Delete .csv columns based on partial header pattern

Tags: linux

Does anyone know of an awk or linux command that removes .csv file columns based on a partial pattern match within header? I tried many examples, but it either did nothing or removed all columns.

```
Example: I want the columns removed that have the header name "(RAW)" within it.

G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP01_OPER_ID(RAW),G_TP02_PROC_NO,G_TP02_PROC_NO(RAW)
4008636142,4008636142,4008636142,4008636142,4008636142

Desired output:

G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP02_PROC_NO
4008636142,4008636142
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have 4 headers and 5 data columns

Comment: Yes hek2mgl, I meant to post just a snippet of a very large file and accidentally didn't match the headers and data columns correctly. Per my comment below, there are many fields that have the "(RAW)" pattern (about 200 or so) throughout the header that I need to remove via partial pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$3}' OFS="," file

G_TP01_OPER_ID,G_TP02_PROC_NO
4008636142,4008636142
```

Comment: I apologize,  this appears to only remove columns 1 & 3. I was in a hurry when I posted this, but I meant for it to remove all the columns with "(RAW)" in the headers, which is about 70 or so throughout a very long header row. My fault for not explaining that.

Comment: This is what I meant in the previous comment:  "I apologize,  this appears to only retain columns 1 & 3. I was in a hurry when I posted this, but I meant for it to remove all the columns with "(RAW)" in the headers, which is about 200 or so throughout a very long header row. My fault for not explaining that. So I need it to remove the columns based on a partial pattern "(RAW)" . It would also be nice if there was an opposite command to retain many columns based on a partial pattern (for a different file of mine).  Thanks!"

Comment: Hi Claes : your answer would be better with some context. If you include an explanation of how/why this is intended to solve the questioner's problem, it is easier to understand - both for the questioner themselves and for other readers looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: In my post I just showed to print the columns with now RAW.
Evidently there are many more columns and I have tried to 
elaborate with !/RAW/ not print columns with RAW and have
not succeeded at all. Sorry I cant produce any better!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell version, to be fed via standard input:

```
read
fields=-f
sep=
i=0
IFS=,
for field in $REPLY
do  # collect fields without "(RAW)"
    ((i=i+1))
    if [[ $field != *"(RAW)"* ]]
    then    # output header name, append field number to $fields
            echo -n "$sep$field"
            fields+="$sep$i" sep=","
    fi
done
echo
cut -d"," "$fields"
```

Comment: Armali, where do I place my argument (input file) with this script?

Comment: @Adrian Chavez: By _to be fed via standard input_ I meant input redirection such as `script <input_file`.

Comment: Okay, let me try this. Thank you!